# Differences between "output of" and "output from"?

Tags: differences

Is there any rule as to when to use "the output of..." or "the output from..."? Is it one more formal than the other?

Thanks

Comment: Please include your research.

Comment: Please provide the context to your question. *Output* can be used in a very wide range of situations. Consider, for example, *the output of iron from the mine*.

Answer (score 4):

I think "of" is slightly more accurate because outputs are not really "caused," they "are/exist". I think for the most part they can be used interchangeably in the way you're using it. I don't think one is more formal than the other in the way that you're using it.

Most accurate definitions I chose for your example:

- of - "indicating an association between two entities, typically one of belonging."
- from - "indicating a cause."
- from - "indicating the source or provenance of someone or something." [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS713US713&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cause%20defintiion)
- of - "What's the output 'belonging to' this equation?" - What's the output of this equation?
- from - "What's the output 'caused by' this equation?" - What's the output from this equation?

Similar example, you could say, "I'm of the Southern region," which sounds kind of weird,  but it means you belong to the Southern region. I've heard it used that way before. The more common way to say that is: "I'm from the Southern region," which is using the "provenance" definition. Output is not really the provenance/source, it's the result.

Great question, it seems simple but I think there's more to it.